# Reduce values in several columns and rows of a database using a php loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a client that requires a new function adding to an existing solution.

They store financial data in a MySQL database with the below columns. These are all
outstanding payments, some with penalties, and some without.

```
ID | money_id | principal | interest | penalty | paid_pri | paid_int | paid_pen

 1      1         50          60         5          0          0          0
 2      1         55          55         5          0          0          0
 3      1         60          50         0          0          0          0
```

In the case above, the client has two penalties to pay on the ID 1 & 2, if the
customer pays $200, then the interest and penalties need to be paid first before
paying the principal payments. once all outstanding interest & penalties are paid
the principal payments can be paid off.

The new table, after the 200 is paid should look like this.

```
ID | money_id | principal | interest | penalty | paid_pri | paid_int | paid_pen

 1      1         50          60         5          25         60          5
 2      1         55          55         5          0          25          5
 3      1         60          50         0          0          50          0
```

This is because the allocation of 200 pays, 60 + 5 + 2 5 + 5 + 50 
then 25 off the first principal.

Edit For MARC B's point:

> how can i "Reduce values in several columns and rows of a database using a php loop"

I have to work with an object, returned from mysql.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [interest] => 60
            [interestPaid] => 0
            [penalty] => 5.00
            [penaltyPaid] => 0
            [principal] => 50
            [principalPaid] => 0.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [interest] => 55
            [interestPaid] => 739.10
            [penalty] => 5
            [penaltyPaid] => 739.10
            [principal] => 55
            [principalPaid] => 0.00
        )
)
```

I have to use this to loop through the database, its called $payment_array.

My code so far, bearing in mind they have a class which extends mysql ($this)

```
$amount_to_pay = 200;

foreach ($payment_array as $ordered_repayment) {
            if ($amount_to_pay > 0) {
            $interest_balance = $ordered_repayment['interest'] - $ordered_repayment['interestPaid'];
            if ($interest_balance > 0) {
                $sql = "update schedules set paid_int = paid_int + '" . $interest_balance . "' where id = '" . $ordered_repayment['id'] . "'";
                $amount_to_pay -= $interest_balance;
                $this->query($sql);
            }
            $penalty_balance = $ordered_repayment['penalty'] - $ordered_repayment['penaltyPaid'];
            if ($penalty_balance > 0) {
                $sql = "update schedules set paid_pen = paid_pen + '" . $penalty_balance . "' where id = '" . $ordered_repayment['id'] . "'";
                $amount_to_pay -= $penalty_balance;
                $this->query($sql);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($payment_array as $ordered_repayment) {
        if ($amount_to_pay > 0) {
            $capital_balance = $ordered_repayment['principal'] - $ordered_repayment['principalPaid'];
            if ($capital_balance > 0) {
                $sql = "update schedules set paid_pri = paid_pri + '" . $capital_balance . "' where id = '" . $ordered_repayment['id'] . "'";
                $amount_to_pay -= $capital_balance;
                $this->query($sql);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this is a bit more verbose ;)

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring that out. Did you have a question?

Comment: @MarcB No need to be sarcastic. (me being sarcastic now).

Comment: I can't see a way to do this in a single SQL query (well, not one I would want to even try to write or maintain), but in php without worrying too much about performance it is easy. Just loop though the results set updating a row at a time and knocking the amount off the payment until the payment amount is zero, or loop around again knocking it off the principle.

Comment: @Kickstart ive added som ecode i wrote earlier today, to show my train of thought with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would slightly amend things to avoid the need for 2 updates on some rows:-

```
<?php

$amount_to_pay = 200;

foreach ($payment_array as $ordered_repayment) 
{
    switch (true)
    {
        case $amount_to_pay <= 0 :
            break;
        case $amount_to_pay > ($ordered_repayment['interest'] + $ordered_repayment['penalty']) :
            $sql = "UPDATE schedules 
                    SET paid_int = paid_int + " . $ordered_repayment['interest'] . ", 
                    paid_pen = paid_pen + " . $ordered_repayment['penalty'] . ", 
                    interest = 0, 
                    penalty = 0 
                    WHERE id = " . $ordered_repayment['id'] . "";
            $amount_to_pay -= ($ordered_repayment['interest'] + $ordered_repayment['penalty']);
            break
        case $amount_to_pay > $ordered_repayment['penalty']) :
            $sql = "UPDATE schedules 
                    SET paid_int = paid_int + " . ($amount_to_pay - $ordered_repayment['penalty']) . ", 
                    paid_pen = paid_pen + " . $ordered_repayment['penalty'] . ", 
                    interest = " . ($ordered_repayment['interest'] - ($amount_to_pay - $ordered_repayment['penalty'])) . ", 
                    penalty = 0 
                    WHERE id = " . $ordered_repayment['id'] . "";
            $amount_to_pay = 0;
            break
        default :
            $sql = "UPDATE schedules 
                    SET paid_pen = paid_pen + " . $amount_to_pay . ", 
                    penalty = " . ($ordered_repayment['penalty'] - $amount_to_pay) . " 
                    WHERE id = " . $ordered_repayment['id'] . "";
            $amount_to_pay = 0;
            break
    }
}

foreach ($payment_array as $ordered_repayment) 
{
    if ($amount_to_pay > 0) 
    {
        $capital_balance = $ordered_repayment['principal'] - $ordered_repayment['principalPaid'];
        if ($capital_balance > 0) 
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE schedules 
                    SET paid_pri = paid_pri + " . $capital_balance . " 
                    WHERE id ='" . $ordered_repayment['id'] . "";
            $amount_to_pay -= $capital_balance;
            $this->query($sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll integrate this shortly and test it out :)